# How to make inequality sign and equality sign into a string

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I'm trying to make an array of strings which are all '<=', '>=' and '='.
This is the code I made:

```
del_str=np.zeros((Nnodes*ndofs),dtype=str)
    for i in range(Nnodes*ndofs):
        if dels[i]>0:
            del_str[i]="<="
        elif dels[i]<0:
            del_str[i]=">="
        else:              
            del_str[i]="="
```

I think this should work but when I check it with print I get only these:

```
['=' '=' '=' '=' '=' '=' '<' '>' '<' '>' '>' '<' '>' '>' '>' '>' '>' '>' '>' '>' '>' '>' '>' '>' '>' '>' '>' '>' '=' '=' '=' '=' '<' '>']
```

Where did I go wrong?? I even tried these:

```
del_str=np.zeros((Nnodes*ndofs),dtype=str)
    for i in range(Nnodes*ndofs):
        if dels[i]>0:
            del_str[i]="<"+"="
        elif dels[i]<0:
            del_str[i]=">"+"="
        else:              
            del_str[i]="="
```

but it still doesn't work. Please let me know what I'm missing..

Answer (score 3):

Your [datatype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) only allows for one character to be stored.  Try:

```
del_str = np.zeros((Nnodes*ndofs), dtype='|S2')
```

demo:

`dtype=str`:

```
>>> del_str = np.zeros(10, dtype=str)
>>> del_str
array(['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
      dtype='|S1')
>>> del_str[0] = '<='
>>> del_str
array(['<', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

---

`dtype='|S2'`:

```
>>> del_str = np.zeros(10, dtype='|S2')
>>> del_str
array(['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
      dtype='|S2')
>>> del_str[0] = '<='
>>> del_str
array(['<=', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
      dtype='|S2')
```